# Why can't the list display?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, structure

The C program asks to display an initialized `List`. The `get3rdYear` removes all the students with the year level 3 from List P. All the 3 year students will be moved to a new List and returned to the calling function. the function `displayBSIT` displays the student name from the list if the course is BSIT. The function `displayList` display the full name of the students in the list. The problem in this program is that when it runs, no initialized data displays but the black screen only.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char fName[16];
    char lName[16];
    char mI;
}Name;
typedef struct{
    int id;
    Name fullName;
    char course[20];
    int yrlvl;
}Record;

typedef struct node{
    Record student;
    struct node *link;
}*List;

void initList(List *P);

//create the following functions:
List get3rdYear(List *P);
void displayBSIT(List P);
void displayList(List P);
/*
    get3rdYear-> removes all the students with the year level 3 from List P.
        All the 3 year students will be moved to a new List and returned to the 
        calling function.
    displayBSIT-> displays the student name from the list if the course is BSIT
    displayList-> display the full name of the students in the list
*/

int main(void){
    List L, thirdYear;
    initList(&L);
    displayBSIT(L);
    //thirdYear = get3rdYear(&L);
    displayList(L);
    //displayList(thirdYear);
    //initalize L by calling initList()
    //call displayBSIT()
    //call get3rdYear(), thirdYear will recieve the list returned by get3rdYear()
    //display L and thirdYear
    return 0;
}

void initList(List *P){
    int ndx;
    List temp;
    Record arr[] = {{12, {"Chris", "Vergara", 'S'}, "BSIT", 3}, {32, {"Dione", "Cabigas", 'A'}, "BSCS", 4}, {85, {"Jomer", "Barcenilla", 'G'}, "BSIS", 1}, {98, {"Danise", "Hinoguin", 'B'}, "BSIT", 1}, {456, {"Francis", "Aliser", 'C'}, "BSCS", 3},{888, {"Cody", "Ng", 'A'}, "BSIS", 3},{32,{"Jason", "Carreos", 'S'}, "BSIS", 3}};
    *P = NULL;
    for(ndx = 0; ndx!=7; ndx++){
        temp = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(temp != NULL){
            temp->student = arr[ndx];
            temp->link = *P;
            *P = temp;
        }
    }
}

List get3rdYear(List *P){
    List temp;
    temp = *P;
    while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->student.yrlvl == 3){
            printf("%d\n",temp->student.id);
            printf("%s %s %c\n",temp->student.fullName.fName,temp->student.fullName.lName,temp->student.fullName.mI);
            printf("%s\n",temp->student.course);
            printf("%d\n",temp->student.yrlvl);
            temp = temp->link;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

void displayBSIT(List P){
    List trav;
    trav = P;
    while(trav != NULL){
        if(trav->student.course == "BSIT"){
            printf("%d\n",trav->student.id);
            printf("%s %s %c\n",trav->student.fullName.fName,trav->student.fullName.lName,trav->student.fullName.mI);
            printf("%s\n",trav->student.course);
            printf("%d\n",trav->student.yrlvl);
            trav = trav->link;
        }
    }
}

void displayList(List P){
    List trav;
    trav = P;
    while(trav != NULL){
        printf("%d\n",trav->student.id);
        printf("%s %s %c\n",trav->student.fullName.fName,trav->student.fullName.lName,trav->student.fullName.mI);
        printf("%s\n",trav->student.course);
        printf("%d\n",trav->student.yrlvl);
        trav = trav->link;
    }
}```
````

Comment: for the function `displayBSIT`, yes

Comment: no warnings, no error during compiling

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems both in this function:

```
void displayBSIT(List P){
    List trav;
    trav = P;
    while(trav != NULL){
        if(trav->student.course == "BSIT"){
            printf("%d\n",trav->student.id);
            printf("%s %s %c\n",trav->student.fullName.fName,trav->student.fullName.lName,trav->student.fullName.mI);
            printf("%s\n",trav->student.course);
            printf("%d\n",trav->student.yrlvl);
            trav = trav->link;
        }
    }
}
```

First, `==` does not compare character strings in C.  Since character strings are actually the address of the first character in memory, it doesn't make sense to do this kind of comparison.  Since I'm guessing you're doing homework, I'm going to let you work through how you *do* compare character strings in C.

The more important advice here: if your compiler didn't already tell you that, you're doing something wrong.  When I run it through https://repl.it (I have to change `conio` to `stdio` because `conio` is proprietary), I get the following warning:

```
> clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:84:33: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
        if(trav->student.course == "BSIT"){
                                ^  ~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

You can see it's running under [clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), which is a respected and high quality compiler.  The most important thing for you to know right now is that *your* compiler should be warning you that you made a mistake, too.

Okay, second problem.  Let me clarify the `displayBSIT` code:

```
void displayBSIT(List P){
    List trav;
    trav = P;
    while(trav != NULL){
        if(trav->student.course == "BSIT"){
            printStudent(trav->student);
            trav = trav->link;
        }
    }
}
```

Think about that for a sec.  While the current node is valid, if the current node's student's course is `BSIT`, print and go to the next node.  What's going to happen if the current node's student's course is *not* BSIT?  Will we proceed to the next node?

These two problems work together. Your comparison doesn't work, and your iteration doesn't work, and so your program doesn't provide any interesting output.